# Generating all possible allocations of objects into k bins of size n1,n2,...nk in C++

Tags: c++, combinations

I'm trying to write C++ code which will compute all possible orderings of groups of integers, whose sizes are given in a vector (unknown in length).

For example, if the input is (group1=2, group2=3, group3=2), then I need to compute every ordering of the first 7 integers, in groups of 2, 3, and 2.

Groups matter in avoiding duplicates (i.e. 1234567 is the same as 2134567 which is the same as 1234576).

The output should be:

```
1234567
1234657
1234756
1235647
...
6734512
```

But there could be as many as 10 different groups given (usually the size of the group is less than or equal to 5)

I'm still fairly new to C++, but it seems like I need to use next_permutation from algorithm, possibly in recursion, but I haven't been able to work out the details.

The following is working (inefficient) R code I've written, (in case my question was unclear) but it's far too slow for reasonably large group numbers/sizes.

Thanks!

```
#Input group sizes for k;
CombnMult<-function(k){
n<-sum(k)
A1<-combn(n,k[1])
CHOOSE<-rep(0,length(k))
CHOOSE[1]<-factorial(n)/(factorial(k[1])*factorial(n-k[1]))
for(i in 1:(length(k)-1)){
CHOOSE[i+1]<-factorial(n-cumsum(k)[i])/(factorial(k[i+1])*factorial(n-cumsum(k)[i+1]))
assign(paste("B",i,sep=''),matrix(get(paste("A",i,sep='')), nrow=cumsum(k)[i]))
if(length((1:n)[is.na(pmatch((1:n),get(paste("B",i,sep=''))[,1]))])>1)  
assign(paste("A",i+1,sep=''),apply(get(paste("B",i,sep='')),2,function(z) rbind(matrix(rep(z,CHOOSE[i+1]),ncol=CHOOSE[i+1]),combn((1:n)[is.na(pmatch((1:n),z))],k[i+1]))))
if(length((1:n)[is.na(pmatch((1:n),get(paste("B",i,sep=''))[,1]))])==1) 
assign(paste("A",i+1,sep=''),apply(get(paste("B",i,sep='')),2,function(z) rbind(matrix(rep(z,CHOOSE[i+1]),ncol=CHOOSE[i+1]),(1:n)[is.na(pmatch((1:n),z))])))
}
t(get(paste("A",i+1,sep='')))
}

#Example:
CombnMult(c(2,3,2))
```

Comment: It's not clear to me how the groups matter.  Are you just looking for all permutations of the first `sum(c)` decimal digits?

Comment: The groups matter because within groups, I don't want repeats.
For example:
1234567 is the same as 2134567 because group 1, which has 2 items, has ranks 1 and 2 in both cases.

Comment: So you're expecting `fact(sum(c))/prod(fact(c))` results?

Comment: Yes, Ben, the large number of results causes R to run slowly which is why I need to translate the code into C++...

Comment: you need to be a lot clearer in your initial explanation.  if there are 'groups' at least use a delimiter to separate them.  this alone would make it much easier to get an idea of what you mean by 'input (2,3,2)'.

Comment: @Gschneider: I've rewritten your title to use more standard terminology.  I hope that's what you meant.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That's exactly what I meant, thank you.

Comment: @blackkettle: I tried to be more clear... Hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
void allocate_to_groups_impl( std::vector<char>& usage, std::vector<int>& order, const std::vector<int>& cumsum, int group, int place, int min )
{
    if (place == cumsum[group]) {
        group++;
        min = 0;
        if (group == cumsum.size()) {
            // the allocation is stored in order, we'll just print it out but you could do something else with it
            for( std::vector<int>::iterator it = order.begin(); it != order.end(); ++it )
                putchar(digitset[*it]);
            putchar('\n');
            return;
        }
    }

    for( int v = min, max = usage.size() + place - cumsum[group]; v <= max; ++v ) {
        if (!usage[v]) {
            order[place] = v;
            usage[v] = 1;
            allocate_to_groups_impl(usage, order, cumsum, group, place+1, v+1);
            usage[v] = 0;
        }
    }
}

template<size_t Ngroups>
void allocate_to_groups( int (&c)[Ngroups] )
{
    size_t sum_of_c = 0;
    std::vector<int> cumsum_of_c;
    for( int* it = c; it < c + Ngroups; ++it )
        cumsum_of_c.push_back(sum_of_c += *it);
    std::vector<int> order(sum_of_c);
    std::vector<char> usage(sum_of_c);

    allocate_to_groups_impl(usage, order, cumsum_of_c, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

- C++11 demo: http://ideone.com/HUy02
- C++03 demo: http://ideone.com/P0QlJ

How it works: A fairly standard enumeration of all permutations of the identifiers, modified so that the identifiers within a single group are forced to be strictly increasing.  At each group boundary, the identifier is allowed to decrease.

Comment: Ben, thank you so much, I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. Sorry, I'm new and don't have enough reputation to vote your answer up. Also, is this your code? If so, I would like to be sure I give you the appropriate credit when (possibly if) the R package is finished.

Comment: @Gschneider: Yes, I just wrote it based on your requirements.  Including a link to my Stack Overflow user page would be an appropriate way of acknowledging authorship.  I'm curious, how much faster is this than the version in pure R?

Comment: @Gschneider: I just made it a little faster (probably).

Comment: @Gschneider: I used some C++11 features, try passing `-std=gnu++0x` when compiling.  Or else replace everywhere I used the `auto` keyword with the correct type.

Comment: And for the (2,3,2) example R takes 0.036 seconds, but for (2,2,2,2,2) it takes 31 seconds... And this isn't anywhere close to how big I'm going to need it....

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! This would have literally taken me months.

Comment: @Gschneider: Fixed it to only need C++03.  See the new link in my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. The past few days I have been trying to figure out how to get the code into R using "R CMD SHLIB". I've read that it seems like R doesn't like C++ code; it instead prefers C code, so I've been messing around with wrapper functions, but am getting in over my head. After a while of searching and trying out SWIG, I was hoping you could point me in the right direction. I think my issue has to do with the C++ template, but I'm not sure. I basically replaced the int main of your code with extern "C" and get an error:
"no matching function for call to 'allocate_to_groups(int*&)"

Comment: @Gschneider: You should be able to modify the signature to this: `extern "C" void allocate_to_groups( int c[], int Ngroups )` and pass the number of groups explicitly.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! If you ever have a complicated math/statistics problem, hopefully I can repay you...

Comment: @Gschneider: I have complicated math problems all the time, so maybe.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do looks similar to a [shuffle algorithm](https://www.google.com/search?q=shuffle%20algorithm&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a).

Comment: Forgive my unfamiliarity with C++, but my initial thought was a for loop, but I wasn't sure how to account for the fact that the number of loops that need to be run will depend on how many different groups are given, which won't be known ahead of time...

Comment: To give a little more detail, I intend to all of the math within R, but for the statistical test that will be done, we must generate every possible order that we could have observed the data in.
From R, I will know how many different lines of output there will be, so the only thing I need C++ for is to fill in these values, which takes forever in R.